# Query date of ANY record returned with group by and having > 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query that returns rows when the oID (m.oID) of one table exists more than once as a foreign key (au.fk_oID) in another table.

**The goal** - To build a query that returns *ALL* duplicate au.fk_oid's, where **at least one** of them has an insert date within a range

```
SELECT 
    m.oid, m.DrugName, date(m.drugstart), date(m.drugend), au.action, date(au.insert_time)
FROM
    p_medication_auth au
        LEFT JOIN
    p_medication m ON au.fk2_oid = m.oid
WHERE
    au.action IN (5871 , 5873)
        AND DATE(au.insert_time) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY m.oid
HAVING COUNT(au.fk_oid) > 1
```

Of course, querying the dates in this way with the *group by* and *having >1* will only look for instances where au.fk_oid appears more than once on the same day.

I need to return instances where au.fk_oid appears more than once where at least once of those instances has a date *(date(au.insert_time))* within the range.

Comment: I was finishing an answer to a question you just deleted. Pity to waste it, so I'll slap it here, since I can't find any other contact details, for whatever it's worth.

Comment: === A database is a database, established or otherwise. You connect to it using [`mysqli_connect`][1] or [`PDO::__construct`][2], depending on your choice of database drivers. 

If your dashboard code resides on the same server (ie. you can use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`), you're good to go. Otherwise, you will need to configure your MySQL server to [allow remote connections][3] (to particular IPs/ranges, rather than wide open!), and possibly configure your server's firewall to match. 
...

Comment: I would strongly recommend that, for development purposes, you make a clone of the "established database" and work on it locally, instead of interfacing dev code with a live/production database. When you're satisfied with testing and debugging your dashboard code, then upload it to the production server.

As for "_where do the files get stored on the server_", that entirely depends on your web server setup. A common public HTML folder location might be `/home/username/example.com/public_html/` on a Linux-based webserver, presuming you've configured a virtual host for `example.com`.

Comment: If you're using Apache, and haven't configured virtual hosts, the default document root is `/var/www/html/` in modern systems.
P.S. It's a good idea not to hard-code absolute paths all over your codes -- especially if you're hopping between Windows and Linux for dev and hosting environments. Rather, have all paths configured at a single location; or better yet, derive/define them dynamically based on the running environment.

  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
  [2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `case..when` statement after your query while removing the condition `AND DATE(au.insert_time) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND CURDATE()` from `WHERE` part of the clause

```
SELECT m.oid,
       m.DrugName,
       date(m.drugstart),
       date(m.drugend),
       au.action,
       date(au.insert_time)
  FROM p_medication_auth au
  LEFT JOIN p_medication m
    ON au.fk2_oid = m.oid
 WHERE au.action IN (5871, 5873)
 GROUP BY m.oid
HAVING COUNT(au.fk_oid) > 1
   AND MAX(case when date(au.insert_time) between date'2019-01-01' and curdate() then 
                1
           else
                0     
           end)=1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=346c2bdca25219524a689a6c45e5e10d)</kbd>

Comment: @MikeDWakelyn Thank you too friend :)